# ext js 4.1 :how to make only one column editable at a time

Tags: grid, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a grid with the following 3 columns.[image]

I want to make the Spend & discount fields editable.But one should be editable at a time.If am editing discount column then spend field should not be editable and the value of spend field should changed to the following based on the value in discount

Spend= Spend before Discount +(Spend before Discount*Discount/100);

vice versa for editing Spend field

How can i do this?I request for a complete example.Some one please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Listen to the `beforeedit` event that gets fired. IF you `return false` editing will be cancelled, so you can do your check in there.